# What is a regular expression for parsing key = value using C's regex.h lib

Tags: c, regex

I need an expression which would much **key=value** line
Actually you might have between **"key" and "=" "value"** as many whitespaces as you want
so key   =   value is valid as well. But multivalue should not be allowed.

So something like this:

```
**key = value1 value2**
```

is not allowed.

I've already tried with

```
**const char* regexCheckValidityForKeyValue = "([[:print:]]{1,})([:blank:]*)(\\=){1}([[:blank:]]*)([[:graph:]]*)";**
```

But this does not really work.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: A posix regular expression is needed.

Comment: something like this? `([\w]+)\s*=\s*([\w]+)`http://regex101.com/r/bP5yJ3

Comment: Please be more specific. In what way does it "not really work"? How exactly are you calling regcomp? (Which flags do you pass, for example?)

Comment: Most of the parentheses are unnecessary. With the fix for the missing character class brackets, and repeats simplified, that's `([[:print:]]+)[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*([[:graph:]]+)` ... which is of course basically identical to what @abc123 wrote.

Answer (score 1):

At least to me, it appears that using a regex for this is entirely unnecessary. Getting the code correct will be comparatively difficult, and reading it even more so.

I'd just use `[sf]scanf`:

```
if (2 == (sscanf(input, "%s = %s %s", key, value, ignore))
    // it's good: just `key = value`
else
    // malformed
```

Basically, this attempts to read and convert a key, a value, and a second value. It then checks the return value to see how many of those were matched. If exactly two matched, you have "key = value". If fewer than 2 matched, some part of `key = value` is missing. If it matches more than that, you have `key = value1 value2` (and possibly more after value2), so that's malformed as well.

As a bonus, this also gives you the actual strings that made up your `key` and `value` without any extra cruft.

Answer (score 0):

(Decided to put the comment as an answer instead...)

You're close - just put the first [:blank:] inside a character class as you've done with the rest of them. Then remove the escaping of the '=' i.e. : `([[:print:]]{1,})([[:blank:]]*)(=){1}([[:blank:]]*)([[:graph:]]*)`, or if your flavor supports shorthand - `(\w+)\s*=\s*(\S+)` which is a bit easier to read (or at least shorter ;)). Also captures only the key and the value, not the spaces and stuff that your regex does.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The "print" class includes the space character `0x20-0x7e`, which is making the key allowed to have spaces, or basically could match all spaces as a key.

I assume this is extended POSIX.
There are problems in your description.

The only way to not allow a second 'value2' is to put edge conditions at the end.
But, not much is known about that.

**modified** Since there is no way to negate a posix class, you have to be specific to stop part delimeters from being included in key/value.

```
 #   ^[[:blank:]]*([[:alpha:]][!-<>-~]*)[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*([!-<>-~]+)[[:blank:]]*$


 ^                          # BOS
 [[:blank:]]*               # space or tab

 (                          # (1 start), KEY
      [[:alpha:]]                # start with alpha char
      [!-<>-~]*                  # any chars not equal sign nor whitespace
 )                          # (1 end)

 [[:blank:]]*               # spaces or tabs

 =                          # equal sign

 [[:blank:]]*               # spaces or tabs

 ( [!-<>-~]+ )              # (2), VALUE any chars not equal sign nor whitespace


 [[:blank:]]*               # spaces or tabs
 $                          # EOS
```